# Suppose that there exists $q \in Q_{ml}(R)$ such that $ D(x) = x^{\sigma}q - qx^{*}$ for all $x \in R$. Then $q \in Q_{ms}(R)$.

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

My question is the following Lemma.

Throughout this question, $R$ always denotes a prime ring with involution ${*}$ and an automorphism $\sigma$, which is not commutative.
An additive map $D: R\rightarrow R$ is called a Jordan $({*}, \sigma)$-derivation if $ D(x^2) = D(x)x^{*} + x^{\sigma}D(x)$ for all $x \in R.$

> **LEMMA:** Suppose that there exists $q \in Q_{ml}(R)$ such that $ D(x) = x^{\sigma}q - qx^{*}$ for all $x \in R$. Then $q \in Q_{ms}(R)$. Here $Q_{ml}(R)$ and $Q_{ms}(R)$ are the maximal left quotient ring and maximal symmetric ring of quotient respectively.

**PROOF:** The definition of $Q_{ms}(R)$ is the set consisting of the elements $x$ such that
$xA\subseteq R$ and $Bx\subseteq R$ for some dense right ideal $A$ of $R$ and some dense left ideal $B$ of $R$.

Now, $ D(y) = y^{\sigma}q - qy^{*}$ for all $y \in R$. Since $q \in Q_{ml}(R)$, $\lambda q \subseteq R$ for some dense left ideal $\lambda$ of $R$. Note that $\lambda^{\sigma}$ is a dense left ideal and $\lambda^{*}$ is a dense right ideal of R. For $y \in \lambda$, we have to prove $ qy^{*} = y^{\sigma}q - D(y) \in R$ ? But how could I show $y^{\sigma}q \in R$ ? That is, $\lambda^{\sigma}q \subseteq R$ ? Or we have to find a  dense right ideal $J$ of $R$ such that $qJ \subseteq R$. Then this will proves that $q \in Q_{ms}(R)$, but I was unable to find such an ideal.
    Please give me some hint. How could I prove it?

Comment: Your definition of $Q_{ms}(R)$ is a little bit different from that given by BRESAR in his book Introduction to Noncommutative Algebra. What's a dense left ideal for you? For me $I$ is a dense left ideal of $R$ if for all $x\neq0$ and $y$ in $R$ there exists $r\in R$ such that $rx\neq0$ and $ry\in I$ (see LAMBEK - Lectures om Rings and Modules).

Comment: Yes the definition of dense left ideal of R is correct as you said.

Comment: In case of semi prime ring, the definition of $Q_{ms}(R)$ = \{ $x \in Q_{mr}(R)$: $xA, Bx \subseteq R$ for some $A$ and $B$ of $F$\}, where $F= F(R)= \{A (ideal): ann(A) =0\}$ since $ann_{l}(A)=ann_{r}(A)$. In the case of prime ring, $F(R)$ is just the family of all nonzero ideals, since ann of every non zero ideal is zero.  By using prepositions (14.1) and (14.7) of the book "LECTURES ON MODULES AND RINGS" by T.Y. LAM the definition of $Q_{ms}(R)$ can be redefine as $Q_{ms} as above said.

Comment: Also T.K.LEE and et.al used the above said definition in Lemma (2.1) of his paper "Jordan ${*}$-derivations of prime rings(2014). J. Algebra Appl.13(4):9 pages".